# How to use UIGestureRecognizers for Tap, Pinch, and Rotate on multiple UIViews or UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing, uigesturerecognizer

I don;t know how to handle this :-/

I just need to add stickers on an image. App will conatins  stickers like smilies, hearts (images) on selecting the particular sticker it will be added to main image and user can manipulate with sticker, Like he rotate, scale etc, User can select multiple stickers and can do rotation scaling etc with added stickers,

please guide how to achieve this, I able to perform image maniuplation with single sticker i dont how to perform it for multiple stickers selection, User can again come back to any sticker and perform operation on that.

Comment: do you mean to say you rotate one sticker, and all the stickers rotate.?

Comment: no user will select one sticker by tapping on it , only that sticker will rotate, scale or move

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add gestures using this method:

```
- (void) addGestureRecognizers{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:rotateRecognizer];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinch:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
}
```

and implement those selectors:

```
- (void) move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.superview];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x+translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y+translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.superview];
}

- (void) rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"Rotate");
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(
                                                        recognizer.view.transform,
                                                        recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;
}

- (void) pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1; 
}

- (void) longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"Long Pressed");
}
```

**NOTE**: Change values as you want

Comment: when any sticker is selected is there need to create a new UIImageView each time ?
and then add Gestures to that View

Comment: I can't say anything without seeing your code mate. what do you mean by var? *confused*

Comment: o o Thanks anyways,, It will help Actually I need to add stickers on a image like other photo apps does.. I have multiple stickers
now do you suggest to add a imageview for each sticker .

Comment: ahh ok. Yes you have to add an UIImageView to each sticker you gonna use. Otherwise there is no way to show the stickers init? btw You can up-vote or accept my answer if it helped you :P

Comment: Yes i got it , one more thing ,I will have multiple imageviews .. how can i get which image is selected and on which imageview i have to perform roation,scaling etc

Comment: recognizer.view will give you the imageView that you have to perform rotation, scaling, etc

Answer (score 0):

i'm expecting you are adding gestures to image view when you click on particuler image you want to perform some action on that particuler image right ,then try like this may be it'l helps you

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
```

...

```
- (void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIView *selectedView = sender.view; 
    //perform action here

    or

  sender.view.frame=newFrame;//you can set your frame
}
```

add this one for Simultaneous gesture recognization.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES:
}
```

Comment: yes , but i don't know how to proceed further , like how to perform rotation,scaling etc on selected view

Comment: I want guidance when any sticker is selected I need to create a new UIImageView for each sticker, Then how to add  gestureRecognizer to this new view

Comment: for that after creation of your imageview you can add gestures on that image view